# Unity 2d sprite takes 1 draw call and tk2d sprite used 2 for same

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

i am using unity 4.6
i which i used new ui tools when i create sprite it takes one draw calls
for example

UI system

Sprite0

Sprite1

.

.

.

.

Sprite1000

For illustrate my Question i create a sprite and copy it 1000 times in new Unity 4.6 but it still takes one draw call. but in case of TK2D sprite it takes 2000 draw calls is there a solution kindly share it.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention my sprites has collider and some scripts functioning ..

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a sprite batcher in toolkit 2d:

http://www.2dtoolkit.com/docs/latest/tutorial/using_the_static_sprite_batcher.html

Comment: I tried Static Sprite Batcher but it fails because my sprite has colliders and scripts on them.

Comment: And when an object has script and applied batcher the script is removed by batcher.

Comment: above link is now 404

Comment: Thanks @ShaunNeal, I'm updating it to the latest, which I should have done in the first place.